# Running TestNG automation test on iOS real device - iPad

Tags: ios, automation, appium

I am trying to run TestNG automation scripts on an iOS real device - iPad iOS version 9.0.2 and 10.2. I had successfully installed Appium version 1.5.3 and Xcode version 8.0 When I am trying to run test scripts. I am getting an error.

```html
[debug] [iOS] App is not installed. Will try to install.

[MJSONWP] Encountered internal error running command: Error: Installing /Users/appxpress/Desktop/PGTNQC.app failed
   at /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-ios-driver/node_modules/node-idevice/main.js:159:6
   at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:193:7)
   at emitTwo (events.js:100:13)
   at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:185:7)
   at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:850:16)
   at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:323:11)
   at emitOne (events.js:90:13)
   at Socket.emit (events.js:182:7)
   at Pipe._onclose (net.js:475:12)
```

When try prelaunch with version appium 1.4.16

```html
Could not pre-launch appium: Error: Could not find Automation.tracetemplate in any of the followinglocations /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/PlugIns/AutomationInstrument.xrplugin/Contents/Resources/Automation.tracetemplate,/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/PlugIns/AutomationInstrument.bundle/Contents/Resources/Automation.tracetemplate
```

I have tried below ways to research on the issue.

1) Have downgraded Appium to 1.4.16 and checked.
2) Have switched with two different OS X EI Captain version 10.11.6 and 10.11.5
3) Switch xcode version to 7.3 version and tried

I have followed some turorials to get some knowledge on "How to run on Real device"

I am getting an error when installing .app file on real device through automation scripts and as well as I could not get that done when I directly load through appium with pre launch app.Here I have added udid and force device and Platform version respectively.

Can Anyone please explain me on this, That is that anything related to version mismatcing of xcode Appium versions or else anything related to .IPA file and build configurations?

Your help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appium 1.5.3 supports iOS 9.x and below versions with Xcode7 which has UIAutomation.

For supporting iOS 10.x, need to upgrade Appium to 1.6.x and Xcode8. In this, XCode8 uses builtin XCUITest (part of XCTest) for automation purpose.[Appium 1.6.x supports iOS 9.x also]

*Appium 1.6.x uses WebDriverAgent. 
**Note:** Appium 1.5.3 doesn't support iOS 10.x. and Xcode8

Ensure your app is debug enabled .app/.ipa

**Solution**

1. Appium 1.5.3 + Xcode 7 + iPad iOS 9.0.2
2. Appium 1.6.3/4beta + Xcode 8 + iPad iOS version 10.2/9.0.2 (Ref: Appium Release)

Comment: Is this issue anything specific to Mac OS version OS X EI Capitan version 10.11.6? Before OS update it worked fine.

Comment: Will this combination of version will work out Appium 1.5.3 + Xcode 8 + iPad iOS version 9.0.2 with Mac OS version OS X EI Capitan version 10.11.5? Appreciate your answer

Comment: No, You have to use Xcode 7 for appium 1.5.3 and iOS 9.0.2. But the recommendation is use Appium 1.6.x + Xcode 8 + iOS 10.x.